# EvalInSandBox in Chrome extension API

Tags: firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

Does Chrome extension API has similar function to the Firefox EvalInSandbox?

I know the extension itself is running in a sandbox but my intention is to download JS code from my server and run it within the extension (so if there is no EvalInSandbox in Chrome then what is the best way to accomplish this task?)

THANKS ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There has been good discussion on the [Chrome Extension Mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-extensions/browse_thread/thread/ebe2ec804f5f18e1/07fe5b642af0fef4?pli=1) for this feature. And there is a feature request for it too: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=66689

Comment: It seems like [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com) is solving this issue. Mohamed - what do you think about it?  (it's not like developing native Chrome extensions but it generate native Chrome crx + native FF & IE so it looks really cool!)

Comment: Native in terms of plugins most likely since it has its own unique processing. That is too overkill if thats the case. Concerning your question, can't you add permission to your website and just import the script to your background page. And if you have any content scripts, you just use Extension messaging to transfer data back and fourth.

Comment: Executing code in a sandboxed page without Chrome APIs is possible, see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox and https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval